# How to gitignore *only* files?

Tags: git, gitignore

I'm surprised that simple patterns like *.user in a .gitignore file seem to match files **and** folder names.

```
ringods$ mkdir TestIgnore
ringods$ cd TestIgnore/
ringods$ git init
Initialized empty Git repository in /Users/ringods/Projects/hostbasket/TestIgnore/.git/
ringods$ git status
# On branch master
#
# Initial commit
#
nothing to commit (create/copy files and use "git add" to track)
ringods$ mkdir security.user
ringods$ touch security.user/file_may_not_be_ignored.txt
ringods$ git status
# On branch master
#
# Initial commit
#
# Untracked files:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
#
#   security.user/
nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)
ringods$ echo "*.user"> .gitignore
ringods$ cat .gitignore 
*.user
ringods$ git status
# On branch master
#
# Initial commit
#
# Untracked files:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
#
#   .gitignore
nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)
```

Do I have the wrong expectation? How can I write a simple *ignore files with extension blah* and prevent folders ending in *.blah* being matched?

The [gitignore man page](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitignore.html) mentions that patterns without a / are matched using shell glob pattern functionality, but it doesn't really tell me if it matches files only or files and directories.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

`.gitignore` patterns just match directory entries or paths. There's no specific way to say "only match a regular file", however if you supply a trailing `/` then the pattern will only match a directory. You can use this to match non-directories (which is almost what you want) with two patterns:

```
*.user     # ignore all paths ending in '.user'
!*.user/   # but don't ignore these paths if they are directories.
```

Comment: Note that this will match `/folder.user/file.user` (the negated pattern allows anything in `*.user/`)